# Get the log of connection attempts INCLUDING the login name in a SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql, azure, connection

I need to know the log of connections for a given time frame in a SQL Azure Database.

I've tried this view:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_connection_stats
WHERE database_name='myDatabase'
ORDER BY start_time desc
```

Getting a table with just these columns:

- database_name
- end_time
- success_count
- total_failure_count
- terminated_connection_count
- throttled_connection_count

But **NO login name** associated!

Also tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Getting plenty of information but just from the **current connections** and I need to have a **log of attempts**.

Is there a way to get a log of connection attempts with user logins **in SQL Azure**?

Thanks